# Optimize this horrible regular expression

Tags: regex, optimization

The idea is to allow only four instances of 'a' and two instances of 'b' in a string of arbitrary length.

Now, the other characters don't matter, all I care about, is four 'a's and two 'b's. All I came up with, is this:

```
m{
  ^[^ab]*
  (
    (b[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (b[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a)|
    (b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b)|
    (a[^ab]*b[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*b[^ab]*a)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*a[^ab]*b)|
    (a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*a[^ab]*b[^ab]*b)
  )
  [^ab]*$
}x;
```

*(as always, this is Perl regex)*

Is there a better solution to this, other than merely regrouping the cases with additional parenthesis? Permuting the accepted cases seems a bit "wrong" in regex terms to me.

*This question was asked on stackoverflow under a different pretext. The question was removed back then, since it was poorly written, no attempt at solving was made, and it was more than clear, that it was an assignment for a TCS course. I tried answering the question anyway and was presented a message, that the question has been deleted (in the mean time). The problem at hand seems quite interesting to me anyway, so I decided to ask it again, but with a better pretext.)*

Comment: Why would you use regex for this in the first place? In my opinion it's a rather inefficient use of resources - simply parsing the input text using a for() loop (character-by-character) would yield an answer with less CPU. It'd likely be more portable, too, since this code would become a lot more complex and error-prone just by adding one more character to conditions.

Comment: Because it's a challenge in the first place, and second, it's a nice way to prove that those kind of strings are strings of a regular language.

Comment: polemon, the faq states "you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". If this is indeed a real problem, the right answer is to avoid regexes. If not, it probably shouldn't be here.

Comment: @paxdiablo The point is basically whether it is possible to simplify that kind of regex, or not, and if so, how.

Comment: If this is simply a challenge with no real practical value, perhaps it belongs on codegolf.stackexchange.com instead.  You can frame it as "what's the shortest regex that can do this."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Four `a` requirement:

```
[^a]*(?:a[^a]*){4}
```

Two `b` requirment:

```
[^b]*(?:b[^b]*){2}
```

Combined by encapsulating the first requirement in a lookahead:

```
^(?=[^a]*(?:a[^a]*){4}$)[^b]*(?:b[^b]*){2}$
```

Comment: Just for reference: without lookaround, would it be possible to shorten my regex?

Comment: @polemon, no, don't think so. (Except for minor cleanups and regroupings, but it still would work the same way.)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution to this is (pseudo-code):

```
def hasFourAsAndTwoBs (s):
    numAs = 0
    numBs = 0

    for each ch in s:
        if ch == 'a':
            if numAs == 4:
                return false
            numAs = numAs + 1
        if ch == 'b':
            if numBs == 2:
                return false
            numBs = numBs + 1

    # Get rid of this if it's "up to" 4 as and 2 bs rather than "exactly".
    if numAs != 4 and numBs != 2:
        return false

    return true
```

In other words, regexes cease to be useful when they become bigger than code that does the same thing in a more readable fashion.

Use the right tools for the job and optimise for readability *first.*

Comment: +1 for Use the right tools for the job. I'd still be interested in seeing if it's possible to improve the regex though.

Comment: As a matter of interest, I understand. But if one of my minions delivered a regex like the one in this question, I'd force them to print it out on 200gsm paper and eat it, then I'd send them back to do it properly :-)

Comment: Yes, well, that wasn't the point here. This was simply a challenge to prove that the regular language defined by the textual constraint, is indeed a regular language. Your point is still valid though, concerning the right tools, for the right reasons, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If using PHP, here's by far the easiest solution:

```
if( substr_count($input,"a") == 4 && substr_count($input,"b") == 2) { /* OK! */ }
```

I'm sure plenty of other languages have a similar function.

As paxdiablo said, if your regex is longer than the code to do it otherwise... use the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string !~ m/(?:.*?a.*?){5,}|(?:.*?b.*?){3,}/x)
```